# LibGDX Scene2D.ui - Resizable composite widget

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have a custom widget, composed by a button and a text field:

```
public class MyWidget extends Table {

  private Button button;
  private TextField textField;
  private MyWidgetStyle style;

  public MyWidget(Skin skin, String styleString) {

    super(skin);
    this.style = skin.get(styleString, MyWidgetStyle.class);

    this.button = new Button(style.buttonStyle);
    this.textField = new TextField("", style.textFieldStyle);
    this.textField.setAlignment(Align.center);

    add(button);
    add(textField);
    pack();

    // doesn't seem to make a difference
    //setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
  }


  public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
  }

  static private class MyWidgetStyle {
    public Button.ButtonStyle buttonStyle;
    public TextField.TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle;

    public MyWidgetStyle(MyWidgetStyle style) {
      this.buttonStyle = style.buttonStyle;
      this.textFieldStyle = style.textFieldStyle;
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I create a widget and add it to a table, I don't seem to be able to set its size to less than its preferred one (eg, height), as follows:

```
MyWidget w = new MyWidget(skin, "default");
System.out.println(w.getPrefHeight()); // 35

...

Table table = new Table();
table.add(w).height(20);   // drawn at 35
```

If the value for height() is smaller than 35 (the preferred height), the widget is still drawn 35 units high.
Since the widget extends `Table`, it doesn't have a setPrefHeight() method and anyway, from what I've read, it shouldn't be necessary to explicitly set height on the widget, as setting the table cell height should be sufficient. Now my question is, do I have to implement some other method in MyWidget to have code like `table.add(w).height(20);` work as expected?